# Replacing backlash in dataframe columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas data frame and I want to replace certain values in specified columns. I'm having a hard time replacing `"\"` with `"1"`.

```
 dict = {"\\": "1", "I": "1", "o": "0", "O": "0", "&": "9", "a": "9"}
 df1.replace({"P": dict, "#S": dict, "#M": dict, "#L": dict, "#W": dict},inplace=True)
```

Comment: What di you try and what didn't work? [ask] and [mre]

Comment: @Julien I tried the code snippet I posted and it wasn't replacing "\" with "1"

Comment: this is not a [mre]. Also naming your dictionary with builtin name `dict` is a terrible idea.

Answer (score 1):

You missed 2 things:

1. You have to enable raw strings even if you escape `\` character (for regex)
2. You have to set `regex=True` as parameter of `replace` method

```
dmap = {r"\\": "1", "I": "1", "o": "0", "O": "0", "&": "9", "a": "9"}
cols = ["P", "#S", "#M", "#L", "#W"]
df[cols] = df[cols].replace(dmap, regex=True)
```

**Note 1**: don't use [`inplace=True`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/16529), it will be (probably) deprecated in future versions of Pandas.

**Note 2**: don't use Python keywords as variable name like `dict` to avoid unexpected behavior in your later code.